# Entity Framework Foreign Key Connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, frameworks, entity

Here's my controller :

```
  public ActionResult Display(int id)
    {
        Child child = db.Children.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChildID == id);
        ViewBag.ChildName = child.FamilyName + ", " + child.GivenName + ", " + child.MiddleName;

        EducationalHistory eduHist = new EducationalHistory();
        eduHist.ChildID = id;

        child.EducationalHistories.Add(eduHist);

        return PartialView(child);
    }
```

I actually tried to inner join this into multiple tables and I've checked the query it seems correct here's the code:

```
  var chs = from eh in db.EducationalHistories
                  from shl in db.SchoolLevels
                  from shy in db.SchoolYears
                  from ar in db.Areas
                  from sh in db.Schools
                  from gr in db.GradeLevels
                  where eh.SchoolLevelID == shl.SchoolLevelID 
                  where eh.SchoolYearID == shy.SchoolYearID
                  where eh.AreaID == ar.AreaID
                  where eh.SchoolID == sh.SchoolID
                  where eh.GradeLevelID== gr.GradeLevelID
                  select new
                  {
                      eh.ChildID,
                      shl.SchoolLevelName,
                      shy.SchoolYearName,
                      ar.AreaName,
                      sh.SchoolName,
                      gr.GradeLevelName
                  };


        ViewBag.EducationalList = chs;         
        EducationalHistory eduHist = new EducationalHistory();
        eduHist.ChildID = id;
       // child.EducationalHistories.Add(eduHist);

      // ViewBag.SelectList = db.EducationalHistories.Find(id);

        return PartialView(chs);
```

But my problem now is I don't know how to transfer the data from CHS variable to the partial View. 
I mostly past a model value on the view model using a model class. Could I use the viewbag to transfer the queried data ?

Thank you again.

Comment: can you be more clear about "I actually don't know how to connect those Foreign keys to there respective tables so that I could get the Name Equivalent of does ID's. " so that we can try to help u

Comment: I can suggest you to create a viewModel with the same fields as your `Chs` variable, so in your partial view you can declare a model as the  viewModel

Comment: I apologize for that Rudresh, I remove some of the codes that are unnecessary. Thank you Inanikian for the suggestion, but do I really need to create a new model everytime I need to inner join tables ?